# Vlookup Assistance

Tags: vba, vlookup

I have a project where I need to lookup up/match multiple values from `Column B` to match a criteria selected from a drop down list in `Column A`.

The project pertains to different countries and their respective ports.

What formula/VBA code can I use that will allow me to select a country, then auto populates a list of ports? (kind of like a multiple vlookup - results shown vertically)

For Example: attached screenshot shows `column A` (**Country**) and `Column B` (**Port**). I want to select e.g. *China* and then automatically be able to populate the respective ports highlighted in green.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I think this question is too broad. You're asking us to write the code for you... I've voted to close unless you edit your question and put in the VBa you've attempted.

Comment: Public Function MultiVLookup(MatchWith As String, TRange As Range, col_index_num As Integer)
    MatchWith = LCase$(MatchWith)
    If (MatchWith = "") Then
       MultiVLookup = ""
    Else
        For Each cell In TRange
            If LCase$(cell.Value) = MatchWith Then
                x = x & cell.Offset(0, col_index_num).Value & "/"
                           End If
        Next cell
        If (x = "") Then
           MultiVLookup = ""
        Else
           MultiVLookup = Left(x, Len(x) - 2)
        End If
    End If
End Function